# Dealing with whitespace in text areas with a minimum character count

Tags: textbox

We have a form with a text area where a user must enter a minimum number of characters, say, 50 characters. We also have a character count that counts upwards as the user types.

The problem is that a user can just type 50 spaces and pass the validation. We can trim the whitespace from the beginning and end of the input before validating but that results in an error message that is something like: "You must enter at least 50 characters" but the character count will show that a user *did* enter at least 50 characters.

Is there a best-practice for how to handle whitespace in text areas with a minimum character count?

Is there a special error message that is needed? Something like: "Please enter at least 50 characters not counting beginning and ending whitespace" is very clunky to me.

[image]

Comment: don't tell anything to the user, just sanitize the input and that's it

Comment: The problem is precisely because we have a minimum character count. A user enters 60 characters but pads it with 15 spaces at the end so in effect, they really only entered 45 characters of actual input so, when we sanitize, it no longer meets the minimum and we need to surface the error to the user in some way. As in, the form they're submitting fails to submit. The question is what's the best way to handle this.

Comment: sanitize so spaces aren't counted as characters. You already have a counter, so the user will see that adding spaces do nothing. Also, I have seen sites that don't allow two spaces together or several enter jumps (as a matter of fact Facebook does the enter thing and not sure if spaces as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There's several levels to this:

#### Minimum character count is probably not a good thing to have in the first place.

Yes, there's only so much entropy you can put into a character, but some cases really just need a few words to be effective. For example, consider this forum exchange:

> Alice: Hello, I have a problem where [..., lengthy explanation of the problem]
> Bob: Have you tried turning it off and on again?
> Alice: That was it, thanks!

In this exchange, Bob is at 43 characters and would need to pad his answer somewhat (a "Hello Alice" would be sufficient), and Alice would need to increase the length of her answer 2.5x to convey the exact same information. And it also doesn't *really* help you with getting a better conversation going; when faced with this limit, Alice might just try one of these instead:

> Alice: That was it, thanks! (silly text I have to type to hit the minimum)
> Alice: That was it, thanks! bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
> Alice: That was it, thanks! And please remove this dumb limit.
> Alice: That concludes our conversation, I appreciate your time and help.

(the last option there is LLM-generated, and while more verbose, got confused as to what "it" refers to)

Most of the minimum-limit-enforced versions of a post are going to be worse than those without, if the user genuinely already has said everything that needed to be said.

#### Counting should be relative

Instead of "20/50 characters minimum", you can have a "50 characters minimum" before entering any text, and then switch to a text saying "49 more characters before you can post" as soon as the first letter is in there. That way, your character counter isn't a competitor to [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) for some sort of objective character count truth, but rather a progress indicator.

##### Character counting has exceptions already

For example, take the "character" ️‍. This isn't actually a character, but rather a white flag emoji, a variant selector 16, a zero width joiner and a rainbow emoji. So a user typing in one "character" is actually rewarded with 4 characters as far as unicode knows, but actually is 6 characters as far as Javascript knows (`"️‍".length === 6` because the emoji are 2 bytes in UTF16).

Twitter also has a special rule for URLs, where no matter the length, they're always 20 characters.

#### Users already know what your intention is

Character limitations are known to most users, and it's pretty evident what you're trying to do. Given that you have a realtime display of how many characters remain, they'll see the count tick up whenever they type actual characters. If you then don't count whitespace at the beginning and end of the string *and show you don't count it in the realtime display*, it's a very quick learning experience for anyone not yet familiar with the pattern.

#### Don't error out, disable the post button

Greying out the post button next to the "49 characters remain" progress indication gives a pretty clear indication as to what people need to do before completing the task and prevents frustration.

### Putting it all together

With all of the above, Devin's comments really are the solution: There's no need to go into edge case error messages, simply sanitize the input and show the user that adding spaces doesn't make them progress.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. Follow-up question: when you say that a character counter should not count whitespace, does that include the middle of a few sentences of input as well? For example, a user type: "This restaurant was so " - would the counter not count the last space until a new character is typed?

Comment: That is the way this typically works, yes.